# sublime text regex to find filename with certain extension

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I am needing a regex to find filenames in a text document. The text document has several instructions along with filenames. I want to only find the filenames. Below are examples of the filenames.

- For the version 5.2, select the BS - PRX 5.2.txt file
- For the version 2018, select the BS - QAW 2018.txt file
- For the version 9.0, select the BS - VDXX 9.0.txt file
- For the version 9.1, select the BS - VDXX 9.1.txt file
- For the version 10.0, select the BS - OKJL 10.0.txt file
- For the version 11.0, select the BS - OKJL 11.0.txt file

What I am wanting is to pull out the filename that starts with BS and ends in the .txt regardless of what is in the middle.

Here is what I've tried but only gets the whole line and gets other lines I don't need with other beginning filenames.

^.*.txt.*$

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`(BS.*\.txt)`

Extracts text starting with `BS` and ends with `.txt`.

Heres's the [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/FzVQiZ/1)

Comment: That worked perfectly! but how do I remove any duplicates, thats the next issue

Comment: what duplicates..? give some more example test cases

Comment: I figured it out. Sublime has a built in duplicate line remover.

Comment: @B3nd3r, you should explain how you solved it by adding an answer to your own question, to help others.